# Кривая граница элемента

Tags: html, css, css3

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сверстать границу как на этом скриншоте?
Граница, которая после изображения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант на основе статьи "[Геометрические фигуры на CSS](https://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/)". С помощью псевдоэлементов [`:before`](https://webref.ru/css/before) и [`:after`](https://webref.ru/css/after) делаем два треугольника, которыми закрываем нижние углы фотографии.

Псевдоэлементы добавляются до и после содержимого контейнера, поэтому контейнер является родительским блоком по отношению к своим псевдоэлементам. Позиционируем  контейнер относительно, а его псевдоэлементы - абсолютно, чтобы [вести отсчёт координат от краёв контейнера](https://webref.ru/css/position#field_css_value).

`bottom: 0;` прижимает нижние края треугольников к нижнему краю контейнера. Аналогично `left: 0;` и `right: 0;` задают положение для левого и правого края.

[`1vw`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#viewport-relative-lengths) равен 1 проценту от ширины области просмотра.

И назначаем картинке свойство `display: block;`, чтобы между нею и контейнером не возникало лишних просветов.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.container:after,
.container:before {
  border-bottom: 3vw solid white; 
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}
.container:before {
  border-right: 50vw solid transparent;
  left: 0;
}
.container:after {
  border-left: 50vw solid transparent;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghlee.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот такой вариант есть, через `clip-path`:

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  clip-path: polygon(0 45%, 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 45%, 50% 65%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 45%, 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 45%, 50% 65%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUsNL.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Каеф, думаю это то, что нужно

Comment: Вау, в первый раз услышал этом стиле clip-path . Это же реально крутая штука - обрезать что угодно и как угодно можно! И никаких костылей с border и border-radius. И поддерживается вроде как отлично https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/ . В чём подвох?

Answer (score 1):

Привет. Я более чем уверен, что такие вещи реализуют либо через canvas, либо через графический редактор. Думаю, что второй путь будет более безопасным и менее трудоемким. Я тебе нарисовал эти границы. Один в формате png, другой в .cdr (Файл CorelDraw). Достаточно будет переместить на верхний слой и все будет точно также, как на картинке которую ты прислал.

[Вектор](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B99KJj2T_bOfWVh0ZlZrWmt5MEU)

[Растр](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B99KJj2T_bOfaTF1M1dIUlVLZXM)

Comment: Вряд ли через canvas, скорее всего картинкой. Можно SVG base64 бэкграундом в css, по мне так лучший вариант, хотя svg не растянешь на всю ширину

Comment: да, полностью с Вами соглашусь. Возьму себе на заметку

Answer (score 1):

Интереснее всего через `clip-path`, но на это ответил уважаемый @MasterAlex.
Можно извратится и сделать через `canvas` (скорее просто так, в работе используйте `clip-path`):

```js
function draw() {
  let canvas = document.querySelector('header canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    width = canvas.width,
    height = canvas.height,
    bg = new Image();

  bg.src = 'http://worldinsidepictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/p-1.jpg';
  bg.onload = () => {
    // Сразу ставим загруженную картинку в canvas
    ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
    
    // Рисуем вогнутый пятиугольник
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ccc";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, height * .85);
    ctx.lineTo(width / 2, height * 0.95);
    ctx.lineTo(width, height * .85);
    ctx.lineTo(width, height);
    ctx.lineTo(0, height);
    ctx.fill();
  }

  // Просто так, чтобы удостоверится что работает меню
  document.querySelector('#menu').addEventListener('click', e => alert('Menu!'));
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', draw);
```

```css
header {
  width: 634px;
}
header canvas {
  display: block;
}
#menu {
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <canvas width='634' height='369'></canvas>
  <div id='menu'>Hello, world!</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну или такой костыль

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 512px;
  height: 154px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25%;
  width: 200%;
  left: -50%;
  height: 150%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 80px 0 0 #CDCDCD;
}
```

```html
<div><img src='http://static.tumblr.com/f245a30826dacb1b692c774279da16ef/9qglsht/fvommjlre/tumblr_static_header-background.jpg' width='512'></div>
```